# Drag Drop Portlets in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, portlet, portal

I want to create a portal interface in Drupal, with drag drop portlets. I should also be able to create my own portlets.
I came across the following link http://aymanh.com/drag-drop-portal-interface-with-scriptaculous, but that is only compatible with Drupal 4.
Any other way to implement the required functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 6 you could take a look at Dashboard, it should achieve something similar to what you require.

http://drupal.org/project/dashboard

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the [jQuery interface sortable](http://drupal.org/project/interface_sortable) module but it looks promissing. You will probably need to make some code yourself, but it should help you along.

With Drupal you can use any jQuery plugin, so you might do better searching for a jQuery plugin to assist you. Most of the work will be done in js anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). Is there any out of the box module that might work ?